# Program to Convert decimal to hexadecimal in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to convert decimal to hexadecimal in VC++(MFC Application) ?
THANKS.

Comment: Every one who have answered so far has assumed that you don't mean what you actually asked, and have given you the solution for formatting a number into hexadecimal format. You asked for conversion from decimal to hexadecimal, which would mean that you have a string containing a number in decimal format as input, so do you need the conversion from decimal to number also?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: Can you add a snippet of sample code (or something other than a link) so I can upvote this?

Comment: The link I posted has an example of precisely converting numbers to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

MFC you say?

```
CString bla;
int yournumber = 15;
bla.Format("%x", yournumber );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean converting an int into a hex string, this would be a C++ solution:

```
int num = value;
string numHexStr;
stringstream ss;

ss << hex << num;
ss >> numHexStr;
```

You can add the uppercase manipulator for, well, uppercase. e.g.

```
ss << uppercase << hex << num;
```

If you want something more Cish you can use sprintf with %x or %X to get lower or upper case accordingly. e.g.

```
sprintf(str, "%x", num);
```

Comment: @hilel : I am getting hex decimal value of 172 as "ffffffAC" i just want to reterive "AC". how to do that ?

Comment: @Swapnil: Can you add the code you are using (I presented two alternatives, both work fine when I test them on my machine).